# TypeScript: Type of Key of Object?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define the following types:

```
type Item = {
    name: string,
    value: number | string
}


type ItemFilter<T extends Item> = {
    property: keyof Item;
    value: // ?????? I'd like to have here the type of Item[property]
}
```

How can I set `value` to have the type of item's property property?

I'd like to do the following:

```
const myItem: NumberItem = {
    name: 'phoneNumber',
    value: 1111111,
}

const valueFilter: ItemFilter<NumberItem> = {
    property: 'value',
    value: 11111, // SHOULD BE OK
}


const valueFilter: ItemFilter<NumberItem> = {
    property: 'value',
    value: 'STRING', // SHOULD FAIL
}
```

Comment: Not exactly this, but does this solve your problem? https://tsplay.dev/wOaKlm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do here is value constructor which would generate our proper filter value for our object. Consider the code:

```
const makeFilter = <T extends Record<string, any>> (item: T) => <K extends keyof T>(property: K, value: T[K]) => {
    return {
        property,
        value
    }
}

// TESTS
const myItem = {
    name: 'phoneNumber',
    value: 1111111,
}

const filter = makeFilter(myItem) // create function for specific object filtering

filter('value', 1231)  // ok
filter('value', 'a') // error as expected
filter('name', 1231)  // erorr as expected
filter('name', 'fine') // ok
```

Pay attention that we don't even need any `Item` type anymore, solution will work with every object.

Some explanation:

- `makeFilter` is a function which derives types by arguments
- it firstly get our initial object and return function which has arguments only for this specific object type
- `filter = makeFilter(obj)` creates our needed filter constructor for specific object
- using `filter` after has already proper narrowed types in the arguments
- `property: K, value: T[K]` means that value needs to be value of the object under the key - `K`

### Why I have used function and not type directly.

Function allows us for type inference over arguments, so we don't need to repeat redundantly types. We just make filter for wanted object.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMBiBLANlFAnGAXhgB4AVGFAD1zABMIYAlFUPOk6PDMAcwBoYCMAE8AfGJgAKDLjgAuGGQCURSSQDSlGinqNUIkADMlYqQAc8Ic-igjFGwQDcEWAK4pFZANoaAuqqEkgDeALAAUDBRMHgoUG54YDBhkdFplta2IvwRaWku7ii50QC%20EWXhEQD0VUoAogDKZA0RoJCwcCIAknJEycVRYAhwnjAA5OYAFuAoAHJucABG%20GM5qVEFHooAjLt722sVreDQMEbYuATEiKiYOPhSnT0ocKo1MMCxCLhnbmDAUAw4DOIAIEBswAw52AMBAiwAVqxYOd7tw%20BEIijLlIxpsUKsYNsAEwAZm2qhg7xASExFweuNcHgJYwQYzetXwVgICEY1AhuDotNROKGIwJxLJFPe%20FB3N5VH5KEF4Sx9NF%20MEY3OYHx7NhNMq4XedChRnwulgshex3a8G6ciJfRSaQQvFGxLWaUhdkUYwAMm5FlgeKtyhjwm1Tqq8I7rsh0HS8I97S8iXrPihvihfv9AcCjKCYODWFCMDC4YiAWdEzxeOHo0Sca6NYTSeSolSDQ2m27may9ZzCzztIrld2xt6ROK21KOVy5SOkUqhZdGxPZFPNdrdZTatSIkA)